# Isolated scope: value not updating

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to expand on the bootstrap ui library with my own custom control. This control will be used in an AngularJS app. Currently, I'm getting stuck on the scoping.

[**My plunker is here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/2Fwt2ZbcR53dMuE5Uril?p=preview)

This plunker is a simplified version of a more complex control. The concept that I'm trying to highlight is the scoping. You will notice that the custom control, my-query, is pre-populated with the value of `myController.$scope.query`. You will also see that the query is put in the page underneath the custom control. As I type, the value does NOT get updated. Why? My code looks like the following:

```
myApp.directive('myQuery', [function() {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
          query: '='
        },
        template: '<div ng-controller="myQueryController"><input type="text" ng-model="query" /><button ng-click="go_Click()">go</button></div>'
    };
}]);

myApp.controller('myQueryController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.go_Click = function() {
        $scope.$emit("goClicked");
    };  
}]);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: be careful passing primitives to ng-model in nested scopes, should always have a dot in ng-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your directive template, you are adding an additional controller which is adding in another scope.  That is what is causing the problem.  Instead of doing it that way, move the controller logic into either a controller function or a link function defined on your directive, either will work.

Try this.  Here's an example using a controller function.  Note that I moved your original `myQueryController` inside the directive and removed the `ng-controller` directive from the `myQuery` directive's template.

```
'use strict';
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.queryValue = 'test';  

  $scope.$on('goClicked', function() {
    $scope.performAction();
  });  

    $scope.performAction = function() {
       alert('Using ' + $scope.queryValue);
    };
}]);

myApp.directive('myQuery', [function() {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
      query: '='
    },
    template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="query" /><button ng-click="go_Click()">go</button></div>',
    controller : function ($scope) {
      $scope.go_Click = function() {
            $scope.$emit("goClicked");
        };
    }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Very interesting. I guess I have a lot more to learn about scopes in AngularJS.

Comment: https://egghead.io/technologies/angularjs.  Incredible videos for learning Angular.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="myQueryController">
```

A controller creates a new scope. So `<input type="text" ng-model="query" />` doesn't use `query` from the directive's scope but from the controller's scope. Instead of using a controller you can define the `go_Click`function in the directive's link method.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this?:

http://plnkr.co/edit/6IrlnXvsi2Rneee0hGC8?p=preview

```
scope: {
  model: '='
}
```

The problem was that you used a primitive type which was passed by value into your directive. Always use complex types which are passed by reference.